# RSA decryption using only n e and c

Tags: encryption, rsa

I need to decrypt c and I was given only n, e and c and computing p and q or phi(n) would be close to impossible so what other alternatives do I have? I tried calculating p and q but I made very little progress with the search in the last 24 hours of continuous running the program.
These are the values I was given:
`n: 58900433780152059829684181006276669633073820320761216330291745734792546625247`
`e: 65537`
`c: 56191946659070299323432594589209132754159316947267240359739328886944131258862`

Also, in another challenge only `c` and `n` were given and the values were a lot bigger. Do you have any suggestions for that too?

Comment: @LukeJoshuaPark I understand that, but the challenge was supposed to be easy. The challenge description is `You've overheard a discussion between two classmates arguing whether the size really matters.`

Comment: Clearly hinting at the fact that `n` isn't that big yes?  That is your hint.

Comment: @LukeJoshuaPark I figured as much. But still, I have no idea what to do besides trying to bruteforce for the next years or so

Comment: Your factors are: 176773485669509339371361332756951225661 and 333197218785800427026869958933009188427 - thanks to https://sourceforge.net/projects/msieve/

Comment: @Iridium Thanks a lot for the help. As for the second challenge, the hint is something about NP-completeness. Given only `n` and `c` this time do you think that I could use msieve to solve this one too?

Comment: As the size of the modulus increases, the time it takes to factor increases dramatically, even using the fastest classical algorithms (according to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_number_field_sieve whilst it's sub-exponential, it's still super-polynomial). Whilst the above factorization took only 3 minutes, even just a few more digits would likely push that out to days/weeks/...

Comment: @Iridium thanks for the help and information, I will try to find another solution since the new number is 311 digits long

Comment: On the same PC I factored your number above (77 digits), I've managed to factor a 155 digit number in about 20 days. I very much doubt you'll be able to factor a 311 digit value in any reasonable amount of time.

Comment: Note: challenge is from https://2021.redpwn.net/

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Well, it seems that this question is CTF related, because the patterns of n, e, and c are weak numbers.

You can solve it with [RsaCtfTool](https://github.com/Ganapati/RsaCtfTool):

```
python RsaCtfTool -n 58900433780152059829684181006276669633073820320761216330291745734792546625247 -e 65537 --uncipher 56191946659070299323432594589209132754159316947267240359739328886944131258862
```

`timctf{CENSORED}`

Comment: How do I call the RsaCtfTool library from within Python, so I can automate the submission into the challenge using pwnlib?

Comment: @FelixAn You could implement that start on https://github.com/RsaCtfTool/RsaCtfTool/blob/master/RsaCtfTool.py#L22 and example of usages are in https://github.com/RsaCtfTool/RsaCtfTool/blob/master/RsaCtfTool.py#L213

Answer (score 3):

https://www.dcode.fr/rsa-cipher
Try this one but it need p and q. So I use the hand calculator to find p and q.
Using Fact(n), ex: Fact(91)= 7x13, so p=7, q=13